# How to create an encrypted cookie that also has a flag/signature to determine possible tampering(PHP)?

Tags: cookies, encryption, e-commerce

I have been trying to figure out how to store some variables in a cookie in a way to make sure it is both encrypted and signed as to avoid tampering. But I do not know how to create an encryption, and heard it is not a good idea to create my own. I also have no idea how to create a signature. 
How exactly do you create a signature for a cookie? 
How should I go about creating my own encryption to hide the info I am storing in a cookie?

Thank you.

Comment: Seriously, just don't do it. Only put in the cookie an identifier that you use to locate the corresponding information in your own database. For one thing, you can never solve the problem that a user can substitute an older version of the cookie data.

Comment: I will not be storing sensitive information, but I also do not want people to know how I store my information in the database. I need it for a shopping cart. I would like to be able to learn how to sign a cookie, as well as encrypt it to hide how I store it on my database. Again: NON-SENSITIVE information will be stored.

Comment: Just have a column in your database for the cookie. Make the cookie completely random. Store it on the user's computer and in your database. Then, when you get the cookie back, look it up in your database, and there's the data, safe and secure. You're making this way more difficult than it has to be.

Comment: @Andy If it's non-sensitive, don't worry about the user editing it. However, if you really want it to be secure, store it server-side so the user can't see it and can't edit it. Session IDs are a great (and easy) way to store information in this way.

Comment: I see what you are saying. What do you mean by making it random? Like making two cookies, one for the client, a second for the database, and just compare them both to make sure they both match? And sorry, I am daily new to web development, but I am trying to learn.

Comment: @Sonic42 that is also another option. Thank you for throwing around some options. In your case. What would be in the Session ID? A way to the cookie? My only thing with that is I would like to give the user the option to not need to keep logging in. But I could keep the shopping cart data server side.

Comment: @Andy Try reading this tutorial about PHP sessions: http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions.htm

Comment: @Sonic42 Well I know how sessions work. For a shopping cart, this is useful. I could just store it server side (Like david said) and get it, put it in a session and just update as the user makes changes. But how should I go about keeping a user logged in even after, lets say, the computer shuts down?

Comment: By the way, if you know this, can I actually store the whole cookie in the database, or do I need to take the information in it and store it? And if so, what data type do I use for that column to store the whole cookie?

Answer (score 0):

First thing: you need to accept that there is no way to make a cookie secure and a user can always tamper with it.

The only things that you should store in a cookie are basic preferences (like what theme a user wants to see on your site) and identifiers (which I'll talk about below).

If you want to store information about users in a secure way, you can save some sort of ID number in a cookie and have that ID number correspond to data you store on your server.

Comment: Like I told David, I know this. My issue is not what to store. Storing an ID does solve this problem of keeping this private. Assuming that a user uses the site with good intentions, no tampering will occur. But lets assume I just use an ID, what keeps someone with bad intentions from changing the number. That links it to someone else. At that point, I have no way of knowing whether someone changed the cookie to do this.

Comment: @Andy Session hijacking is a possibility. However, if you use a 8-digit numerical ID, there are 1,000,000,000 possible combinations, and the chance that someone could guess a meaningful ID is slim to none. Of course, you could get on someone else's computer and "steal" their ID, but what is the harm in copying someone else's shopping cart?

Comment: This is true, but assuming you have thousands of users and more, the chances of this guess are higher. But I do understand what you are saying. The shopping cart is a thought, but I would also like to give the user the option to keep logged in. Since users will be able to see there address and other information on their profile, I would rather keep someone else from guessing a correct ID by encryption or signing if that makes sense.